# How to deal with DataCollator and DataLoaders in Huggingface?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, dataloader, huggingface-datasets

I have issues combining a DataLoader and DataCollator. The following code with DataCollatorWithPadding results in a `ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.` when I want to iterate through the batches.

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=16, 
collate_fn=data_collator)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(eval_dataset, batch_size=16, collate_fn=data_collator)
for epoch in range(2):
    model.train()
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):          
          outputs = model(**batch)
          loss = outputs.loss
```

However, I found annother approach where I changed the DataCollator to `lambda x: x` Then it  gives me a `TypeError: DistilBertForSequenceClassification object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list`

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=16, collate_fn=lambda x: x  )
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(eval_dataset, batch_size=16, collate_fn=lambda x: x)
for epoch in range(2):
    model.train()
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):          
          outputs = model(**batch)
          loss = outputs.loss
```

For reproducability and for the rest of the code I provide you a Jupyter Notebook on Google Colab. You find the errors at the bottom of the notebook.
[Link to Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UboXyiL8Iovg-5ikRoSC-at7fWlFtPIW?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the `train_dataset` object from your notebook:

```py
print(train_dataset)
```

Output:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['text', 'label', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 25000
})
```

`DataCollatorWithPadding` doesn't know how to pad the `text` column because it's just a string.

Since you've already tokenized the dataset, you can simply remove the `text` column like so:

```py
train_dataset = train_dataset.remove_columns("text")
```

The other three columns are all tensors and so can be padded by the data collator. Your first training loop will then run as expected.